# If $V$ is a finite-dimensional rational representation, then the subrepresentation that defines rationality can be taken as $V$ itself

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a linear algebraic group, a representation $(V,\rho)$ of $G$ is rational if exists a finite-dimensional subrepresentation $W\subset V$ such that the map
\begin{align*}
\varphi :&G \rightarrow GL(W)\\
&g\mapsto (v\mapsto g\cdot v)
\end{align*}
is a morphism of linear algebraic groups.

If $V$ is a finite-dimensional rational representation of $G$, I want to show that I can take $W=V$ in the definition above.

I was trying to show that if $W_1,W_2$ satisfy the definition, then $W_1+W_2$ also satisfy, so I can take subrepresentations for each element of the basis and will be done.

I know for example that $W_1\cap W_2$ satisfy the definition and $W_1\oplus W_2$ satisfy the definition for the representation $V\oplus V$.

I tried to use the sequence $W_1\cap W_2\rightarrow W_1\oplus W_2 \rightarrow W_1+ W_2$ with maps $v\in W_1\cap W_2$ to $i(v)=(v,v)\in W_1\oplus W_2 $ and $(u,v)\in W_1\oplus W_2 $ to $u-v \in W_1+ W_2$, this sequence gived me that $W_1+W_2\simeq (W_1\oplus W_2)/i(W_1\cap W_2)$. But I'm not sure if it is the right way to do this.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Any representation is a morphism of linear algebraic groups. What do those two words ('representation' and 'morphism') mean to you precisely?

Comment: @AlexYoucis What my teacher said is that a representation of a linear algebraic group is a vector space with an action of the group in it, such that the action is linear. For morphism, is, in the same time a morphism of groups and the definition of morphism between two ringed spaces seeing the groups as varieties.

Comment: These are basically the same thing. If a group acts linearly on $V$ then this induces a map $G\to\mathrm{GL}(V)$ which is algebraic, so a morphism. If $\rho:G\to\mathrm{GL}(V)$ is a morphism then $g\cdot v:=\rho(g)(v)$ is a linear action of $G$ on $V$.